# # character breaks content for CSV file during download

Tags: javascript, csv, file, download

I have code for downloading  CSV file from some data.

```
  const rows = [ ["Html", "Css", "JavaScript"], ["C #", "C++", "Python"] ];

   let csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," 
          + rows.map(e => e.join(",")).join("\n");
```

```
 const encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
 const link = document.createElement("a");
 link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
 link.setAttribute("download", "my_data.csv");
 document.body.appendChild(link); // Required for FF
 link.click();
```

[image: WITH # character]

When I remove # character from data everything works fine

[image: Without # character]

As I understand `encodeURL` is not encode special symbols that is why href atribute includes `#` symbhol and ignore all after it.

I tryied to use `Blob` too but no result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI?retiredLocale=it :

encodeURI() escapes all characters except:

```
A-Z a-z 0-9 ; , / ? : @ & = + $ - _ . ! ~ * ' ( ) #
```

Use encodeURIComponent instead, but only on the data part, not the whole url. Also note that to let Excel split the fields I have to use the semicolon, the comma doesn't work, but this could be because my locale settings.

```
const rows = [ ["Html", "Css", "JavaScript"], ["C #", "C++", "Python"] ];
let csvContent = rows.map(e => e.join(";")).join("\n");
const encodedUri = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(csvContent);
const link = document.createElement("a");
link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
link.setAttribute("download", "my_data.csv");
document.body.appendChild(link); // Required for FF
link.click();
```